# what is the n-k derivative of $x^n$? Also, why is $n!/k! = ...$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, factorial

I am having troubles finding $\frac{d^{n-k}x^n}{dx^{n-k}}$ where $ k \leq n$ I believe it is equal to $n(n-1)(n-2)....k(k+1)x^k$ but htis is just from obersation, I do not know *why* it's that exactly.

Also, I am having troubles justifying htat $\frac{n!}{k!} = n(n-1)(n-2)....k(k+1)$

Comment: If $n>k$ then every term in the denominator of $\frac{n!}{k!}$ cancels with the corresponding term in the numerator.

Comment: It might be easier to first derive a formula for $\frac{d^m}{dx^m} x^n$ and then substitute $m=n-k$. First compute the first few values $nx^{n-1},x(n-1)x^{n-2},\ldots$ and then use induction to prove the pattern you see is true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start from
$$(x^n)^{(k)}=\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!}x^{n-k},\quad\text{which is easy to prove by induction.}$$
and apply it replacing $k$ with $n-k$:
$$(x^n)^{(n-k)}=\dfrac{n!}{(n-(n-k))!}\,x^{n-(n-k)}=\dfrac{n!}{k!}\,x^{k}. $$

Also
$$\frac{n!}{k!}=\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(k+1)k(k-1)\cdots1}{k(k-1)\cdots1}=n(n-1)\cdots(k+1).$$

Answer (score 1):

$\require{cancel}$

$$\frac{n!}{k!} = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\dots}{k(k-1)(k-2)\dots} = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\dots(k+1)k(k-1)(k-2)\dots}{k(k-1)(k-2)\dots} = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\dots(k+1)\cancel{k(k-1)(k-2)\dots}}{\cancel{k(k-1)(k-2)\dots}} = n(n-1)(n-2)\dots(k+1)$$